# Laravel 5.1 Queue - How to avoid Queue:work command to fetch the in progress job

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, queue

1 Queue with Database drivar.My queue:work command run on everyminute.

I want to execute the job for max 2 attempts and it is working. but the issue is my Queue:work cron runs on every minute and even if the earlier job is in progress it attempts for same job.

How can I avoid the queue:work command to run the in-progress job.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`queue:work` will not try to perform a job that is already being performed since it gets reserved flag at the start of the process. What you might be experiencing is the fact that your job is failing before the next time Cron executes, so it just tries the same job again forever.

You can use `--tries` everytime you invoke `queue:work` to limit the amount of attempts a job will have. So if you run `php artisan queue:work --tries=2`, the job will be attempted to execute 3 times and, if it fails all 3 times, it gets added to the `failed_jobs` table.

Make sure you have prepared your environment (database migration) with `php artisan queue:failed-table`.

Comment: Hi Marco,

Thanks for the reply but I have debug with the log. Queue:work execute a job even it is in reserved . May be I am doing something wrong . I run the queue:work command every minute from schedular and cron is added for schedule:run . 
queue:list is working properly. 
Thanks .